# O(n) linear search of an array for most common items

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, search, big-o

Am trying to write pseudo code for an O(n) algorithm that searches a sorted array for the most frequently occurring elements.

Very new to data structures and algorithms and i haven't coded for about 2 and a half years. I have done some reading around the subject and i believe i am grasping the concepts but i am struggling with the above problem.

This is all i have so far, and i am struggling getting the desired result without the second "for" loop, which makes the algorithm an O(n^2) i believe and i am not to sure how i would deal with more than one frequently occurring element.

Any help or direction as to where i can get help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 A=[i];
 Elem=0; 
 Count=0;
 For (i=0; j< A[n-1]; j++);
      tempElem=A[j];
      empCount=0;
      for(p=0; p<A[n-1; p++])   
          If(A[p]==tempElem)
             tempCount++:
      if(tempCount>Count);
        Elem==tempElem:
        Count=tempCount;
 Print(“The most frequent element of array A is”: Elem “as it appears” Count “times”)
```

Comment: Hint: if array is already sorted, why are you starting `p` back at 0? If you know that the array is already sorted, you know that similar items are going to always be beside each other.

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop is *not* your friend.  :-)

Your loop body should key on just two bits of logic:

1. Is this element the same as the previous one?

   If so, increment the count for the current item (`curr_count`) and go to the next element.
2. Otherwise, check `curr_count` against the best so far.  If it's better, then make the previous element and count the new "best" data.

   Either way, set the count back to 1 and go to the next element.

Comment: Nice, succinct, description of the solution.